# Enable navigation bar on CM10/10.1 on Samsung Galaxy S (1)

Tags: cyanogenmod, navigation, quick-settings

After my phone got wet, all my lower buttons (Home, Back, Options) on my Galaxy S (the first one) are broken and do not work anymore. I already did a factory wipe and re-flashed CM10, but nothing changed, so I think it is a hardware problem.

However, recent Android does have this navigation bar on Tablets and newer Phones with those buttons. Is there some way I could enable this bar permanently on my Galaxy S? I can still go into the settings menu, and I have SSH access to the phone. It would also be possible to flash to CM10.1 if that is required.

Any help greatly appreciated, as I don't want to buy a new phone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set a NavBar on your device by just adding a single line to your build.prop file.

`qmenu.hw.maikeys=0`

also you can disable you current h/w buttons by

give a `#` symbol before

`key 172 HOME

 key 158 BACK

 key 139 MENU`

in file `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl`

ES file Exporer will automatically make a backup for those files. You can use that .bak files if you want to revert.

you can edit build.prop file using [ES file manager app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)

**OR**

You can try flashing zip specified [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1918166)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although I did use "build prop editor" from the market to make the `qemu.hw.mainkeys=0` setting.